# How to find neighboring apartments/self-catering accommodation?

Tags: online-resources, accommodation

We will be traveling to Budapest soon, with a group of 10+ people. Trying to find accommodation for a group seems to result in rather expensive apartments or the options are already booked. We are pretty much okay to split the group up in different apartments, if the apartments are in close proximity.

Everything I have tried so far only results in either one big (expensive) apartment or apartments spread over the city (>3 km) in between.

Is there a way to find neighboring rentals? We are going to Budapest, but I am looking for a more generic approach applicable to other regions as well.

I am aware of sites like [air-bnb](http://www.airbnb.com) and [only-apartments](http://www.only-apartments.com) where you can search for large apartments. I am looking for a way to search for apartments in preferably the same building.

Answer (score 1):

Airbnb provides for this. Sample search gives you 100-150 euros per night for 10 people (which I think is an excellent rate at 10-15 euros pppn):

https://www.airbnb.com/s/Budapest--Hungary?checkin=01%2F16%2F2013&checkout=01%2F21%2F2013&guests=10

Comment: I tried airbnb, but the owners haven't responded yet. Same goed for only-apartments.com. That is why I am searching for 2-3 apartments to be rented.

Comment: -1 since it doesn't answer how to find neighboring apartment rentals

Comment: Hm. I'm quite sure that several of the returned results on Airbnb are actually neighbouring apartments, not big apartments sleeping 15.